# ¿Como convertir una consulta SQL a JPQL o CriteriaBuilder?

Tags: java, sql, join, jpql, criteria-api

Tengo tres Clases: Cliente, Préstamo, Cobrador

- los clientes tienen muchos Prestamos
- los cobradores tienen muchos Prestamos
- un préstamo pertenece solo a un cliente y un cobrador, debe de ser el mismo para ambos
- entre los clientes y los prestamos hay una tabla que contiene los `ID`
  lo mismo para los `Cobradores`

Con esto deseo consultar los clientes por nombre, que tienen un préstamo con un determinado cobrador, los filtros serian los prestamos que tiene un cobrador y a partir de eso obtener los clientes que están relacionados con esos prestamos y filtrarlos por los nombres.

La consulta en [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) la se hacer y la adjunto, pero deseo con esta consulta obtener los objetos tipo `Cliente`

```
    select pcl.NOMBRE, pcl.APELLIDOS
    from cobrador c 
    inner join cobrador_prestamo cp 
    on cp.Cobrador_CEDULA = c.CEDULA
    inner join prestamo p
    on p.CODIGO = cp.prestamos_CODIGO
    inner join cliente_prestamo clp
    on clp.prestamos_CODIGO = p.CODIGO
    inner join cliente cl
    on cl.CEDULA = clp.Cliente_CEDULA
    inner join persona pcl
    on pcl.CEDULA = cl.CEDULA
    where c.CEDULA = 14695183
    and p.SALDADO = 0
    and pcl.NOMBRE LIKE '%julio%'
```

Lo que deseo es usar `JPQL` o `CriteriaBuilder` para construir esa consulta y obtener los objetos de tipo `Cliente`.

Comment: tendrias que publicas las clases JPA de cada entidad (Cliente, Préstamo, Cobrador) para ayudarte

Comment: @Paulker considero que la pregunta es demasiado amplia, deberías de hacer una pregunta sobre como pasarlo a JPQL y otra sobre como pasarlo a Criteria

Answer (score 2):

Te comparto el siguiente código, el primer método extraigo la información de un Datatable, en el cual se busca algo en algún filtro de búsqueda:

```
public String getListaCobrador(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("algunPU");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();  
    boolean all = false;
    String echo = (String) request.getParameter("sEcho");
    Integer paginado = new Integer((String) request.getParameter("iDisplayLength"));
    Integer paginaDesde = new Integer((String) request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"));
    String search = (String) request.getParameter("sSearch");
    int sortColumn = Integer.parseInt((String) request.getParameter("iSortCol_0"));
    String typeSort = (String) request.getParameter("sSortDir_0");

    System.out.println("Data json-->Echo:" + echo + " Paginado:" + paginado + " DisplayStart:" + paginaDesde + " Search:" + search);
    if (paginado == -1) {
        all = true;
    } 
    String msg = null;
    try { 
        CobradorJpaController cobCtrl = new CobradorJpaController ();
        List<Cobrador> lisOfCobrador = cobCtrl.findCobradorByJPQL(search, all, paginado, paginaDesde, sortColumn, typeSort);
        int registros = cobCtrl.getCobradorCount(search);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(null != em){
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return msg;
}
```

En el método de arriba se ejecutan los métodos:

**findCobradorByJPQL** //El cual arroja la lista de cobradores que hicieron match con lo que sea que hayas buscado "Julio"

**getCobradorCount** //El cual arroja un Count! de cuantos match encontró de cobradores!

Entonces: **findCobradorByJPQL**

```
public List<Cobrador> findCobradorByJPQL(String sSearch, boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult, int sortColumn, String order) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    StringBuilder q;
    q = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        //TEN CUIDADO!!! EN JPQL LA TABLA DEBE LLAMARSE TAL CUAL SE LLAMA EN DB OSEA Factura, NO "FACTURA" A JPQL SI LE IMPORTAL EL camelCase
        q.append("SELECT cobrador FROM Cobrador cobrador WHERE 1=1");
        //sSearch es lo que sea que hayas buscado "Juli" o "14695"
        if (sSearch != null && sSearch.length() > 0){
            String[] words = sSearch.split(" "); //por si buscas "Juli 14695"
            for (String word : words)                    
            {
              //cada q.append son en las columnas que quieres que tu filtro busque datos
              String valorParam ="'%"+word.toUpperCase()+"%'";
              q.append(" AND (cobrador.cedula LIKE ").append(valorParam).append(" ");
              q.append(" OR UPPER(cobrador.fkCobrador_CEDULA.fkPrestamo.saldo) LIKE ").append(valorParam).append(" ");
              q.append(" OR UPPER(cobrador.fkCobrador_CEDULA.fkPrestamo.fkCliente_prestamo.fkCliente.fkPersona.nombre) LIKE ").append(valorParam).append(" ) ");
            }
        }
        //las columnas de una tabla, dependiendo a que le des click es lo que vas a sortear
        switch(sortColumn){
            case 1:
                q.append(" ORDER BY cobrador.cedula ").append(order.toUpperCase()).append(" ");                    
                break;
            case 2:
                q.append(" ORDER BY cobrador.fkCobrador_CEDULA.fkPrestamo.saldo ").append(order.toUpperCase()).append(" ");                    
                break;
            case 3:
                q.append(" ORDER BY cobrador.fkCobrador_CEDULA.fkPrestamo.fkCliente_prestamo.fkCliente.fkPersona.nombre ").append(order.toUpperCase()).append(" ");                    
                break;
            default:
                q.append(" ORDER BY cobrador.cedula DESC ").append(" "); 
                break;
        }

        Query query = em.createQuery(q.toString());

        if(!all){
            query.setMaxResults(maxResults);
            query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Entonces: **getCobradorCount**

```
public int getCobradorCount(String sSearch) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

    StringBuilder q;
    q = new StringBuilder();

    try {          
        Number numero;
        //TEN CUIDADO!!! EN JPQL LA TABLA DEBE LLAMARSE TAL CUAL SE LLAMA EN DB OSEA Factura, NO "FACTURA" A JPQL SI LE IMPORTAL EL camelCase
        q.append("SELECT Count (cobrador.pkCobrador) FROM Cobrador cobrador WHERE 1=1");


        if (sSearch != null && sSearch.length() > 0){
            String[] words = sSearch.split(" "); 
            for (String word : words)                    
            {
              String valorParam ="'%"+word.toUpperCase()+"%'";
              q.append(" AND (cobrador.cedula LIKE ").append(valorParam).append(" ");
              q.append(" OR UPPER(cobrador.fkCobrador_CEDULA.fkPrestamo.saldo) LIKE ").append(valorParam).append(" ");
              q.append(" OR UPPER(cobrador.fkCobrador_CEDULA.fkPrestamo.fkCliente_prestamo.fkCliente.fkPersona.nombre) LIKE ").append(valorParam).append(" ) ");
            }
        }

        Query query = em.createQuery(q.toString());

        numero = ((Long)query.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        return numero.intValue();
    } finally{
        em.close();
    }
}
```

Resumiendo los 2 metodos y como resultado, te arroja 1 Objeto tipo List y un int con un count de cuantos match hizo!

Toma en cuenta que si quieres usar JPQL tu Entity debe tener bien marcada las relaciones entre las tablas de tal forma que puedas extraer los resultados como: ***cobrador.fkCobrador_CEDULA.fkPrestamo.saldo*** esto tiene que ser trasparente, un "." es como hacer "JOIN" (cobrador JOIN Cobrador_CEDULA JOIN Prestamo.Saldo)

Espero te sirva, cualquier duda con gusto lo vemos.

Saludos.