# Quesries personalizados con Cretieria de JPA 2 + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, criteria

Estoy teniendo el siguiente inconveniente en JPA 2 e Hibernate (Oracle Xe) con una consulta utilizando CRITERIA. Tengo 3 clases, `Management`, `ManagementState` y `State` con las siguientes estructuras:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "managements", schema = "gestor")
public class Management implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MANAGEMENT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "management_Id_Seq", 
                   name = "MANAGEMENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;    
    private String lastname;
    private String dni;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderBy("id ASC")
    private List<ManagementState> states = new ArrayList<>();

    // no se ponen los getters y setters para ocupar menos espacio
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "managementstatetrans", schema = "gestor")
public class ManagementState implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MANSTATETRANS_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "manstatetrans_Id_Seq", 
                   name = "MANSTATETRANS_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id")
    private State state;

    private Instant createdAt;

    // no se ponen los getters y setters para ocupar menos espacio
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "states", schema = "gestor")
public class State implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STATE_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "state_Id_Seq", 
                   name = "STATE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 150)
    private String name;

    private boolean initialstate;

    private boolean finalstate;

    // no se ponen los getters y setters para ocupar menos espacio
}
```

Con la siguiente criteria, obtengo todos los managements:

```
//CRITERIA
CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Management> cq = qb.createQuery(Management.class);
Root<Management> fromTramite = cq.from(Management.class);

cq.select(fromTramite).distinct(true);

List<Management> allitems = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Ahora bien, el problema es que en cada `Management` me vienen todos los `ManagementStates` que tiene el `Management`. Yo necesito dos consultas (por separadas con esta criteria):

1. Obtener todos los `Managements`, pero que en cada `Management` solo venga el ultimo `ManagementState` (el que tenga `CreatedAt` mayor)
2. Obtener todos los `Managements`, pero que en cada `Management` solo venga el `ManagementState` cuya field `CreatedAt` se encuentre entre 2 fechas dadas.

A ver si me pueden ayudar a solucionarlo. Gracias de antemano a todos por tomarse el tiempo de leer.

Comment: Una duda, existe algun requerimiento que indique que debas usar CriteriaQueries para obtenerlo todo en una sola consulta? Veo que estos queries son muy especificos, y lleva considerable esfuerzo construirlos de esta manera, por lo que te pregunto si has considerado usar [Query y JPQL como lo han hecho en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46751/85215)? =)

Comment: @cavpollo si, la idea seria obtenerlo en una sola consulta, dado que esto va a ir paginado y cuanto menos consultas se hagan va a ser mas eficiente, teniendo en cuenta que va a haber muchas personas en simultaneo consultado esto. Si se te ocurre algo, te lo agradezco

Comment: Suena algo complicado lo que buscas, tal vez el problema sea que necesitas armar primero tu consulta SQL, por la forma en que estructuras tus llamadas a la API de criterios es que pienso eso. En lo particular yo usaría un metamodelo para obtener la validación de tipos de datos y haría la consulta de forma más fluente para que se asemeje más a la consulta SQL que tendrías que hacer, te dejo un recurso esperando que te ayude: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries-metamodel y adicionalmente si logras poner tu SQL, te ayudo a pasarlo a criteria ;)